# Apache Storm Compatibility

Tags: apache, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I tried setting up an Apache Storm Cluster, using Apache Storm 1.0.2 and Zookeeper 3.4.9. Everything worked fine, but I realized that Apache Samoa - What I'm going to use the Cluster for - is only compatible with versions of Apache Storm <1.0.0.

Thus, I downgraded all of the Apache Storm nodes to Apache Storm 0.9.4, but none of the nodes could connect to the Zookeeper. Is Apache Storm 0.9.4 only compatible with older versions of Zookeeper? If so, does anybody know what version of Zookeeper I should use?

I'm extremely new to this so forgive me for any incorrect terminology, etc, I use.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue regarding my connection issues (It's unrelated to the main question). But, I can **confirm** that Apache Storm 0.9.4 is compatible with Zookeeper 3.4.9.